# Script to copy specific cells to another sheet in Google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to make a google spreadsheet with 2 sheets. [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qSNqxajXIWQM6HhO2rmuBOMX0nDgqxFRnSQm_UDNufc/edit?usp=sharing)
The 1st sheet "order" is where I place the order and when I press the "Save" button, I want to update the "data" sheet, bu inserting to it (at the end) the following

order number, date, Number, Description and price.

The order number and date are the same for each product.

The script I wrote for this is :

```
function saveData() {
   var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('order');            
   var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('data');            
   var lastRow = sheet2.getLastRow()+1;


   if (sheet1.getRange('B6') != " ")
       sheet1.getRange('a2').copyTo(sheet2.getRange(lastRow,1), {contentsOnly:true});
       sheet1.getRange('b2').copyTo(sheet2.getRange(lastRow,2), {contentsOnly:true});
       sheet1.getRange('b6').copyTo(sheet2.getRange(lastRow,3), {contentsOnly:true});
       sheet1.getRange('c6').copyTo(sheet2.getRange(lastRow,4), {contentsOnly:true});

   if (sheet1.getRange('B7') != " ")
       sheet1.getRange('a2').copyTo(sheet2.getRange(lastRow+1,1), {contentsOnly:true});
       sheet1.getRange('b2').copyTo(sheet2.getRange(lastRow+1,2), {contentsOnly:true});
       sheet1.getRange('b7').copyTo(sheet2.getRange(lastRow+1,3), {contentsOnly:true});
       sheet1.getRange('c7').copyTo(sheet2.getRange(lastRow+1,4), {contentsOnly:true});

   if (sheet1.getRange('B8') != " ")
       sheet1.getRange('a2').copyTo(sheet2.getRange(lastRow+2,1), {contentsOnly:true});
       sheet1.getRange('b2').copyTo(sheet2.getRange(lastRow+2,2), {contentsOnly:true});
       sheet1.getRange('b8').copyTo(sheet2.getRange(lastRow+2,3), {contentsOnly:true});
       sheet1.getRange('c8').copyTo(sheet2.getRange(lastRow+2,4), {contentsOnly:true});

}
```

My problem is that even if Item 2 and 3 are empty, in the "data" sheet I still get the order number and the date.
Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: To anyone who edited the script, Thank you. It works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten a couple of things :

1. *getRange()* doesn't get you anything you can use directly; it's a local proxy of the range, so to speak.  To get the contained data you need to use *.get Range().getValue()* to get the content of the top-left cell in the range.
2. your *if* blocks aren't blocks!  You need to group all the statements together with parentheses.
3. you can't be sure that a null cell will be *!= " "*!  But, I expect, *getValue()* on its own is 'nullish' enough for your purposes.  *getValue().length > 0* will also work.

Also you can avoid blank lines in "data" if you use an incrementing counter.

So your code could look like this :

```
cntr = 0
if (sheet1.getRange('B6').getValue()) {
  sheet1.getRange('a2').copyTo(sheet2.getRange(lastRow + cntr,1), {contentsOnly:true}); 
  sheet1.getRange('b2').copyTo(sheet2.getRange(lastRow + cntr,2), {contentsOnly:true});
  sheet1.getRange('b6').copyTo(sheet2.getRange(lastRow + cntr,3), {contentsOnly:true});
  sheet1.getRange('c6').copyTo(sheet2.getRange(lastRow + cntr,4), {contentsOnly:true});
  cntr++;
}
/*  next row  */
if ( . . .  ) {
    etc.
    etc.
  cntr++;
}
```